# Treeview: How to change rowheight of title row

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm able to change the rowheight of the normal rows of ttk::treeview with

```
ttk::style configure MyStyle.Treeview -rowheight 25
```

But this command doesn't change the rowheight of the title row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does appear to be any way to change the height of the heading.

The best you can do is to create a custom font and configure the treeview heading
to use it.

'Heading' is the name of the treeview heading style.

```
font create headingfont
font configure headingfont -size 13
ttk::style configure Heading -font headingfont
```

Edit: Per Oliver Scholl's answer, you can use:

```
ttk::style configure Heading -padding {0 20}
```

This will set the top/bottom padding to 20 and the left/right padding to 0.

```
 -padding 20 ; # left/top/bottom/right all the same
 -padding {0 20} ; # left/right, top/bottom
 -padding {0 20 0 20} ; # left, top, right, bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
ttk::style configure Treeview.Heading -padding "0 0 0 0"
```

or

```
ttk::style configure Treeview.Heading -padding {0 0 0 0}
```

The padding option is a list with the order {left top right bottom}.